Is there a way to convert a bayesian credible interval to standard deviation?
I am conducting a meta-analysis and one of the included studies only provides as a measure of dispersion the 95% credible intervals, I would like to know if there is a way to convert it to standard deviation similarly as Cochrane suggest for confidence intervals ((UPPER-LOWER)/3.92)*SQRT(N)

In theory the answer is no. In practice the answer is yes. The intervals are derived using different principles as you probably know but in conventional statistical practice they are usually very similar.
